# ¿Expresion regular numeros, decimales y comas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validación

Me podrían ayudar por favor, tengo esta expresión regular:

```
/^\d{1,18}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

La expresión acepta numero y decimales pero quiero que también acepte comas.

Gracias!!

Esto es lo que quiero obtener

Correcto: 10,000.00
Correcto: 10.00
Correcto: 150,000.00
Correcto: 1,000,000.00

Incorrecto 10,00

Gracias amigos

Comment: prueba con este ejemplo, es funcional y acepta números con coma o punto decimal ^[0-9]+([. ,][0-9])

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplos de que valores son validos y cuales no. De lo contrario seria imposible escribir la expresion que buscas.

Comment: Ayuda amigos! no me funcionaron , si me permite una coma pero solo con dos decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a [este sitio](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=126) esta es una Regex que permite captar cualquier valor monetario con comas y 2 puntos decimles:

```
/^(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! , Si me funciono. :)